# Inherit from UIIMage problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance, uiimage

I created class ChImage from UIImage

```
@interface ChImage : UIImage {
@public
    int ChannelId;
    NSString *ChannelName;
    NSString *Description;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *ChannelName;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *Description;

@end

@implementation ChImage


@synthesize ChannelName;
@synthesize Description;

@end
```

And use it in the code:

```
ChImage *cho = [ChImage imageNamed:img];
        cho = [ChImage imageNamed:img];
        cho.ChannelName = @"something here...";
```

on the line cho.ChannelName application breaks. I need to extend UIImage because I need some extra property in that class but I don't know what am I doing wrong?

Also when I try to get image from UIImageView I got error. I don't know if this have something with upper problem:

```
UIImageView *iw = (UIImageView*) sender;
    ChImage *im = (ChImage*) iw.image;
```

I just try to cast in another part of code and it works. The problem must be in click handling method. This is that method:

```
- (void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIImageView *iw = (UIImageView*) sender;
    ChImage *im = (ChImage*) iw.image;
    NSLog(im.ChannelName);

}
```

Becouse this is a uiscrollview with images inside this is how i attached click event to every image:

```
for (imageToAdd in arrayOfImages)
    {               
        UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToAdd];     

        temp.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 29, 29);
        temp.userInteractionEnabled = YES;      
        x += 29;        

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
        [temp addGestureRecognizer:tap];    

        [scrollView addSubview:temp];

    }
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f39d40'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not recommend to subclass `UIImage`, it is a OO layer on top of `CGImageRef` and have quite allot of *magic* involved.

You could create a wrapper class, and do a **has-a** relationship instead of a **is-a** relationship. Which seems like a much better approach in your case.

- Not: Channel is-a Image.
- Instead: Channel has-a Image.

Like this:

```
@interface Channel : NSObject {
@private
   NSString* _name;
   NSString* _description;
   UIImage* _image; 
}
// The rest…
```

You should probably change the name `description` since it will conflict with `-[NSObject description]`.

Answer (score 0):

You send `+imageNamed:`, but have you implemented this method in your subclass? If not, the message is forwarded to UIImage which will return an instance of UIImage, not ChImage. Since the returned UIImage does not respond to `ChannelName`, your app crashes.

Example (simplified) implementation:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageNamed: (NSString *) imageName
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType: [imageName pathExtension]];
    if ( filePath ) {
        ChImage *theImage = [[ChImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
        // configure theImage here if necessary
        return [theImage autorelease];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Alternatively, you might consider implementing an `-initWith…` initializer and use it to create instances of your subclass.

Comment: How to implement this method, is there any code snippet? What more consider me is that I can't set my additional properties :(

Comment: See the sample implementation in my answer.

Comment: But it still break at this line. Is this how getting of image from UIImageView should be done?
ChImage *im = (ChImage*) iw.image;

Comment: It depends on what class of image you assigned to the UIImageView. If it was a UIImage instance, casting it to (ChImage *) will not make it an instance of ChImage. You have to create ChImage instances yourself using [[ChImage alloc] initWith…]. That said, UIKit documentation does not guarantee that UIImageView will return the same image object you set previously. You should not rely on that. Just create ChImages yourself and retain them somewhere in a model or in a controller to make sure UIKit will not do something like this: [UIImage imageWithCGImage: yourChImage.CGImage].

Answer (score 0):

Dont try to subclass and add the property to that. Instead create your own class with NSObject and try to solve your problem. Because there is a concept called class cluster where in you will have to override some basic methods to get your class to work propoerly.

Checkout the code I have placed:

```
  @interface ChImage : NSObject {
    @public
     UIImage *yourImage;
        int ChannelId;
        NSString *ChannelName;
        NSString *Description;

    }

    @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *ChannelName;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *Description;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *yourImage;

    @end




@implementation ChImage

@synthesize ChannelName;
@synthesize Description;
@synthesize yourImage;

@end
```

And instead of using your code:

```
ChImage *cho = [ChImage imageNamed:img];
        cho = [ChImage imageNamed:img];
        cho.ChannelName = @"something here...";
```

USe it like:

```
ChImage *cho.yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:img];
        cho = [UIImage imageNamed:img];
        cho.ChannelName = @"something here...";
```